# Does $ \int_{M} || \nabla_{M} f||^2 dS = \int_{\Omega} ||\nabla_{\mathbb{R^n}} (f \circ \Phi)||^2g d\lambda,$ hold?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, lebesgue-integral, riemannian-geometry

Let $\Phi: \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow M$ and $M$ a euclidean manifold.

Is it then correct that

$$ \int_{M} || \nabla_{M} f||^2 dS = \int_{\Omega} ||\nabla_{\mathbb{R^n}} (f \circ \Phi)||^2g d\lambda,$$
where $\nabla{M}$ is the gradient on the manifold and $\nabla_{\mathbb{R^n}}$ the standard gradient in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Somehow this equation is something that should hold, but I am not aware of a proof of this. In case, you know how to show it, you can restrict yourself to the case $n=2$ if you like, cause this might simplify things.

I mean I know what the definition of the surface measure is and that we have 
$$ \int_{M} f dS = \int_{\Omega} (f \circ \Phi)g d\lambda,$$

but I am not sure how to see that the way the gradient enters the game here, does not cause any problems.

g is Gram's determinant.

Comment: By Euclidean manifold do you mean Riemannian manifold?

Comment: I mean submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: I see. And are you assuming $\nabla_M$ is the gradient defined by the metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ restricted to $M$?

Comment: @JoshBurby I don't understand this comment

Comment: I'm just trying to understand your definition of the operator $\nabla_M$. My interpretation, which I believe would be the most common, is as follows. If $u$ is a vector field on $M$, then $\left<\nabla_Mf,u\right>_M=\mathbb{d}f(u)$, where $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>_M$ denotes the inner product on $M$ given by restricting the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $M$.

Comment: If your usage of nabla $\nabla$ is to indicate gradients, then the answer is *no*.  There is a relation between your two expressions but it requires an additional linear operator that measures distortion of your metric.

Comment: @RyanBudney could you post this as an answer, if you could explain what the actual relation is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f$ has compact support within the image of $\Phi$. By the invariance of the integral under pullback,

$$\int_M ||\nabla_Mf||_M^2\,dS=\int_\Omega ||\nabla_Mf||_M^2\circ\Phi\,\sqrt{|g|}\,d\lambda.$$

Here $|g|$ is the determinant of the matrix with components $g_{ij}=(\Phi^*g_M)(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})$, and $g_M$ is the metric tensor on $M$ given by restriction of the ambient metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

We can also write $||\nabla_Mf||^2\circ\Phi$ as

$$||\nabla_Mf||^2\circ\Phi=(\Phi^*g_M)(\Phi^*(\nabla_Mf),\Phi^*(\nabla_Mf))=\left<\nabla_\Omega(\Phi^*f),\nabla_\Omega(\Phi^*f)\right>_\Omega=||\nabla_\Omega(\Phi^*f)||_\Omega^2.$$

Here $||\cdot||^2_\Omega$ and $\nabla_\Omega$ are the first fundamental form and the gradient operator on the Riemannian manifold $(\Omega,\Phi^*g_m)$. Thus,

$$\int_M ||\nabla_Mf||_M^2\,dS=\int_\Omega||\nabla_\Omega(\Phi^*f)||_\Omega^2\sqrt{|g|}\,d\lambda.$$